# GitHub - Your account has been flagged

Tags: git, github

У меня был проект, тема которого была не совсем толерантна, и в коде приходилось использовать названия для переменных или функций, содержащие n*gga и тд. Я понял, что это было ошибкой, когда на гитхабе появилось сообщение:

> Your account has been flagged.
> Because of that, your profile is hidden from the public. If you believe this is a mistake, contact support to have your account status reviewed.

Теперь мой код нельзя кому-то скинуть через гит, гитхаб н сохраняет мою активность в виде квадратиков.

Я сделал этот проблемный репозиторий приватным, дважды написал в поддержку, но спустя месяц мне так никто и не ответил... Как мне исправить это. Я не хочу создавать новый аккаунт, ибо на моем аккаунте куча проектов, it's my story)

Comment: Ну хотя бы проект почистили от всех своих нетолерантных надписей, прежде чем в поддержку писать? )

Comment: Скиньте ссылку на репу

Comment: @TotalPusher https://clck.ru/gmvMp

Comment: @timur шутка засчитана

Comment: @TotalPusher Ну, вообще вот ссылка https://github.com/Color-Kat/black-NFT

Comment: А почему мне сразу -3 за вопрос? У меня реальная проблема, мне нужно ее решить

Comment: @Colorkat 404 по ссылке. А "-3" - вам важен рейтинг? Ну я поставил +1 для баланса, вопрос интересный. Если бы он был не по правилам, сообщество жало бы "Закрыть".

Comment: Ну так 404 как раз потому, что он у меня помечен, и его никто не может открыть

Comment: @TotalPusher Блин, так что мне с гитхабом делать? Куда писать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я написал на почту `developer@githubsupport.com`. Спустя неделю мне ответили и восстановили аккаунт.